# stdout and stderr ports in Rebol3?

Tags: stdout, stderr, rebol, rebol3

You can read bytes from `system/ports/input`, and if you convert them from BINARY! bytes to a STRING! of unicode codepoints you get something coherent:

```
>> to-string read system/ports/input
Hello
== "Hello^/"
```

But if you try writing to system/ports/output in Rebol3 you get:

```
>> write system/ports/output "World"
** Script error: write does not allow none! for its destination argument
```

The output port is a field in the object, but it's `none`.  Running an ordinary PRINT command that generates output doesn't make the field get set.  Where is it?

Also while on the topic, where is the stderr port?

Answer (score -1):

Rebol3 Alpha has not completely implemented the standard output and standard error ports yet.